# Number theoretical function with logarithmic properties

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, divisibility, riemann-zeta, conjectures

**Introduction**

This is all about the function $v_a(x)$, what i could find about it and what questions i still have.

First of all, I define $v_a(x)$ as the function that counts how often $x$ is divisible by $a$ with $x>0,a>1$ and $x,a \in \mathbb{N}$. For example $v_2(24)=3$ because $24$ is $3$ times divisible by $2$, whereas $v_2(3)=0$ because $3$ is **not** divisible by $2$.

To make $v_a(x)$ a little more general, I introduced the rule, that

$v_a(a^n) = n$ iff $a^n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Q}$

Now things as $v_4(2) = \frac 12$ are possible (Which, if you think about it, makes kind of sense).

I first thought about it when i was playing a little bit with the Collatz-conjecture ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)). I noticed that Collatz function can be redefined involving $v(x)$ as $3\frac x{2^{v(x)}}+1$ ($v(x)$ without a base always refers to $v_2(x)$).

**Logarithmic properties**

One of the most important properties of the $v$ function is that $$v_a(x*y)=v_a(x)+v_a(y)$$ and its trivial to see why. If you look at the properties of $v_a(x)$ so far, they are very similar to the logarithmic function. And we can even prove that $$\max(v_a(x))=\log_a(x)$$
Proof:

Assume that there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $$v_a(n) > log_a(n)$$
Note that we can write every natural number as $ka^b$ with $k,a,b\in\mathbb{N}; a,k>0; \gcd(a,k) =1$

Therefore $$v_a(ka^b)>\log_a(ka^b)$$ $$v_a(k)+v_a(a^b)>\log_a(k)+\log_a(a^b)$$ $$0+b>\log_a(k)+b$$ $$0>log_a(k)$$
$\unicode{x21af}$

This is a contradiction simply because $k\in\mathbb{N}$

**Other results**

Here are all my resuts about the $v$ function:

By definition, the equality $$\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}} p^{v_p(x)}=n$$
holds for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\implies \sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac {v_p(x)}{\log_p(x)}=1$$
Other things that I managed to prove are
$$\sum_{n=1}^x v_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n(x)$$
or that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{v_a(n)+1}$$ diverges (not very hard to prove results). But the more interesting things are $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {z^{v_a(n)}}{n^s} = \zeta(s)\frac {a^s-1}{a^s-z}$$ for $s>1;a\neq1;z\neq0;a^s\neq z$ which is also quite easy to prove using the Euler product ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product))

My most recent result is $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {v_a(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {v_a(n)}{n^s}\mu(n)$$ where $\mu(x)$ is the Möbius function ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)) (Which is equal to -$\frac {\zeta(s)}{a^s-1}$ see *Edit 4*). This equality can be proved using Möbius inversion ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)) altough the proof is not that easy. If anyone wants to prove it, they are welcome to try and share. I would love to see someone find a simple proof.

**Last note and open question**

Even though it's not really much I found and im not a real mathematician, I think it's quite interesting. I dont know, if this function has already been studied, I couldn't find it anywhere. But if someone knows where to search, I would be happy about references and known results. Or maybe you can come up with other interesting or related stuff. If I´ll find anything else, I´ll make an edit and write it in here.

The only thing I couldnt figure out was a closed form expression of $v_a(n)$ or a formula to calculate it's value. And I really tried. That was frustrating. So if you find a formula, please share it. Share any of your thoughts about $v_a(n)$ if you like.

**Edits**

*Edit 1*

if you plot $v(x)$ for natural number

[image]
it gives a fractal-like structur. I think maybe $v(x)$ could be calculated iteratively.
Also, here is the python code:

```
def v(a, x):
    if a > 1 and x > 0:
        count = 0
        while x % a == 0:
            x /= a
            count += 1
        return count
    else:
        return False
```

*Edit 3*

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) is the wikipedia page to this function

*Edit 4*

See @reuns comment

Comment: Something related is the p-adic evaluation of a number: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html).

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I can refer to what is called the [Ruler function](https://oeis.org/A001511) and the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). For the Thomae's function it happens on the restriction to those rational numbers whose denominators are powers of $2$. The ruler function can be computed iteratively by a few simple boolean operations. But there is no shortcut afaik.

Comment: Please rename it with the notation everyone uses : $\Xi_p(n) = v_p(n)$ defined by $v_p(m p^k) = k, p \nmid m$. You can define $v_{p^k}(n) = \frac{v_p(n)}{k}$ but it is not so useful nor used. Also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_p(n) n^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \sum_{n=1,v_p(n)=k}^\infty n^{-s}$ $=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k \sum_{n=1,p\ \nmid\ k}^\infty (p^kn)^{-s}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k p^{-sk}(1-p^{-s}) \zeta(s)=\frac{p^{-s}}{1- p^{-s}}\zeta(s) $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_p(n) \mu(n) n^{-s}=\sum_{n=1,v_p(n)=1}^\infty \mu(n)n^{-s}=\sum_{n=1, p\ \nmid\ n}^\infty  \mu(pn) (pn)^{-s}=-p^{-s}\frac{1-p^{-s}}{\zeta(s)}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order

Comment: I renamed it. And thanks for your proof